# jboss 4 505 error http version not supported on VPN

Tags: java, .net, web-services, http, vpn

We are calling a web service (jaxws) running on JBoss 4 from one of our .NET, C#,  web services clients.  It is working just fine on our local network, but as soon as we connect to our VPN to test on the production environment it throws a 505 error (HTTP version not supported).  On both our local and production machines, we have tested the services from a Java client while still connecting to VPN and it's working fine for the java client

Any hint regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your production web server is not configured the same as your test web server; it is more restrictive and not allowing the HTTP version that you want.  Ask the server admin for your production server what versions of HTTP are supported.

Another possibility is that on the VPN you have an intermediate proxy that is converting your request from one version of HTTP to another.  Ask a network admin for help.